# Make a bar on top of naviagtion bar in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to insert a bar on top of my WordPress page using a plugin, but it appeared behind of my nav area.

here is what it looks like: https://cherinekurdi.com/home-test/

here is the code I inserted:

```
<div class="hello-head">
<div id="hello-head"> test
</div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
#hello-head {
    z-index: 100001;
}

#hello-head  {
    color: #ccc;
    height: 32px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 600px;
    z-index: 99999;
    background: #23282d;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#hello-head , #hello-head {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 32px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

edit: This is what I want it to look like. 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzX84.png)

Comment: z-index does not work unless the element has `position` of either relative, absolute, or fixed.

Comment: I did tried the positioning. fixed wont allow me to scroll, absolute will make the page shifted to left, relative doesn't change anything at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have an element appear "on top", you need to assign a `z-index` higher than the `z-index` of the element in the background. The default `z-index` is `0`, so you are correctly setting a higher `z-index` on the target element (`#hello-head`) of `10001`.

The problem is that `z-index` also explicitly requires you to set a `position` attribute other than the default `static` in order to work correctly. It depends on how you want your site to 'flow', but you're most likely looking for `position: relative`, which tells the element to position itself relative to its parent:

```
<div class="hello-head">
  <div id="hello-head">test</div>
</div>

#hello-head {
    z-index: 100001;
    position: relative;
}
```

Also note that you have both a class and an ID of `hello-head`, which could lead to confusion. You're using multiple CSS selectors unnecessarily in this regard; you have mutliple `#hello-head` selectors (which target the **ID**), when you **may** have meant `.hello-head` to target the **class**. If you just wanted to purely target the ID, you can combine the multiple selectors, and simply write the above CSS (with the `position` included`) as one selector:

```
#hello-head {
    z-index: 100001;
    position: relative; // Added
    color: #ccc;
    height: 32px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 600px;
    z-index: 99999;
    background: #23282d;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 32px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: No worries regarding the ID and class and on how I organize those css code, that is just to have a clear organized thing for this test.

However, in respond to your explanation about relative positioning. I added this in chrome inspector. It did not change anything, the bar still stay behind the nav bar.

Comment: Ahh, I see the problem on your site. Your `#main-header` has a `z-index` of `99999`, and your **secondary z-index declaration** has higher 'specificity' as it comes later in the DOM. Make sure to use `position: relative` on `#hello-head` and **only** `z-index: 100001`. Simply remove the `z-index: 99999` that comes later on, and your issue will fix itself :)

Comment: Actually, your answer help as I realize the z index CSS is overwritten, now I set it to important and it is now on top but it is now covering the nav bar. I was hoping to push the nav bar down so that this element won't cover it.

Comment: To move your navbar down **below** the 'test', you simply need to set a `top` of `32px` on `#main-header`. Note that it has an inline style, so you **may** need to add an `!important` declaration: `#main-header { top: 32px !important }` :)

Comment: I think this is somehow a part of the solution. I need to set it the `position: relative` and `z-index !important` and add `margin-top` to the nav. But I think it will **create another problem** which will set all other pages that do not have this bar, will have the **additional margin-top** that will look odd, correct? **Question** Is there another way to do this approach with an exception of adding additional margin-top to the nav bar?

Comment: You don't add `margin-top` to the navbar, you add `top: 32px` to `#main-header`. And yes, that will cause problems on pages that don't have the secondary bar. You would need to  actually 'inject' you 'test' **into** the navbar itself in order to not mess up the display on pages that don't include the bar. That could prove very difficult with WordPress due to the fact that it's coming from a plugin. I'd recommend using a consistent navbar layout. But if you want that additional 'test', `position: relative, z-index: 100001` are the way to go, in conjunction with `top: 32px` on `#main-header` :)